# File upload form elements don't work on xamarin ios but its working fine with android

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, webview

i am using webview and in my application there is upload button and its working fine with android but in ios when i click on button it shows options like Take photo, Browse gallery etc. when i click on take photo the application crashes and when i click on browse gallery and pick picture its working fine. 
if there is any solution about to hide or disable only take photo from option or is there another solution.

in xamarin android its working fine. All options in IOS are working only Take Photo option crashes the application.

Comment: Could you please share some of the webview code, the stack trace of the crash, and the exception that's thrown if there is one. If you place an exception catchpoint, and then take a picture, is there a line in your app that Visual Studio displays an Exception over?

Comment: Share the error info please, and check if you add the [Privacy - Camera Usage Description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/security-privacy?tabs=windows#accessing-private-user-data) in the info.plist.